# ItoProcess with log

Tags: finance, stochastic-calculus, random

I would like to use `ItoProcess` to simulate some paths of $r(t)$, a process that follows the sde
$$d\ln\left(r\left(t\right)\right)=\left(\theta-\ln\left(r(t)\right)\right)dt+\sigma dW\left(t\right),$$
where $W\left(t\right)$ is a standard Brownian motion. This is a form of the [Black-Karasinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Karasinski_model) model - the $\theta$ and $\sigma$ are, in my application, not time-varying. Can `ItoProcess` handle this? I tried

```
proc = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]Log[r[t]] == (0.05 - Log[r[t]])\[DifferentialD]t + 
0.2 \[DifferentialD]w[t], r[t], {r, 0.1}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]
```

but that does not work, the problem, I would say, is the `Log[x[t]]` on the left-hand side.

Comment: Why don't you use `y[t]=Log[x[t]]` and solve for `y`?

Comment: Ok, and how exactly could I do that?

Comment: I was thinking of something like this: `ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
  0.2 \[DifferentialD]w[t] + \[DifferentialD]t (0.05 - x[t]), 
 x[t], {r, 0.1}, t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1]]`.